# Does OCD play a major contribution in an individuals suffering from anorexia nervosa?

Tags: social-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, abnormal-psychology

Although  I have seen several studies that did substantiate low self esteem having a significant correlation with anorexia nervosa, but does OCD also play a major contribution in understanding the behavioral patterns  in an individual suffering from anorexia nervosa.
this question came into my mind when i read an article regarding Obsessive compulsive disorder among anorexia and bulimia patients
refrence : 
Lilenfeld, L., Kaye, W., Greeno, C., Merikangas, K., Plotnicov, K., Pollice, C., Rao, R., Strober, M., Bulik, C. and Nagy, L. (1998). A Controlled Family Study of Anorexia Nervosa and Bulimia Nervosa. Archives of General Psychiatry, 55(7), p.603.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. What makes you think OCD correlates with Anorexia?  We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?